# Phase difference of standing waves

Tags: waves, wavelength, superposition, harmonics

> The phase difference of a standing wave is zero.

The above statement is found online when searching about standing waves. However, it doesn't make much sense to me. [image]

Consider the above diagram of a standing wave. We see that the standing wave is formed from the red and blue waves travelling in oppositie directions. Now cleary the phase difference between the red and blue waves is always changing, so why is the phase difference of standing waves 0?

Comment: Some of your confusion might be vocabulary. Phase difference between what and what? For example, when the standing wave is at its peak amplitude, the two traveling waves are in phase. The phase difference between the two traveling waves is $0$. Likewise, when the standing wave is flat, the phase difference between the two traveling waves is $180^o$.